# Navbar not doing the same behavior in Chrome and Firefox

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, browser

i'm doing a website, and even if my code is a little dirty(With some "inline css" that i'm going to remove), it's nearly finished.
My major problem here is that my collapsing navbar is acting very well in chrome, but not in firefox when I resize exactly the same way.
Here is the site : http://www.castegnaro-exterieur.fr/
Let me show you with images:

[image: Here is the navbar collapsing in two rows in Firefox, deforming my Title pushing it bottom]

And here with Chrome there is absolutely no problem

[image: Navbar acting well]

I would like someone to help me correcting this flaw, I think Chrome and Firefox got maybe some differences, like my font-weight is not working too in the title, you can see it bold in Chrome and not bold in firefox even it's the same code of course.
Sorry for my poor english I hope you get my problem, and can help me understand these browsers differences, you can link me some good article if you wish too :).

Comment: Could you share the link to the site which has this issue?

Comment: Welcome to SO. Instead of uploading pictures, are you able to show the `CSS`, `HTML`, `javascript` code? Otherwise, we will all be trying to help you by guessing, which wastes a lot of time for everyone.

Comment: @SatheeshKumar I've added the site of course my bad aha

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The box-model is different between Firefox and Chrome. Chrome uses one that is similar to IE. Refer to this article: [CSS Box Model Differences](https://thomashunter.name/blog/css-box-model-differences-in-firefox-and-internet-explorer/).

I am guessing that this is the root cause of the issues you are seeing.